# Can Anyone tell me why the following error occurs - wrong orientation

Tags: android, eclipse, orientation

The error occurs on the linear layout line below - wrong orientation

```
<android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/action_bar_overlay_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<FrameLayout android:id="@id/action_bar_activity_content"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/top_action_bar"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="top">
    </android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer>
```

Comment: your linearlayout is missing android:orientation="" tag

Answer (score 0):

Layoutgravity value depends on the orientation of your linear layout - horizontal or vertical. Check the orientation of your linear layout. Most likely it is horizontal in which case gravity value of top is not valid